# cannot achieve multiple row-select (ReactJs)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have the following code written so far and it works fine for the usual single selection and sends back the index of the selected row to the parent component (inside the `onClick`  function of `TableRow`. here `item`  is basically the index). I need to get not more than two indexes of two selected rows. I tried to take some approaches but all went in vain.

```
export default function MultiSelectTable(props) {
    const rows = props.value
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);
    const [selectedID, setSelectedID] = React.useState(null);
   
    const renderTH = (headers) => {
        console.log('this is the table info: ', headers)
        if (headers) {
            return Object.keys(headers).map(item => (
                <TableCell
                    key={item}
                    style={{ width: '100vh', backgroundColor: '#b8b8b8' }}><b>{item}</b></TableCell>
            ))
        } else { console.log('no headers') }
    }
    const renderTB = (headers) => {
        if (headers) {
            const rows = {}
            Object.values(headers).forEach(col => {
                for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(col)) {
                    rows[key] = rows[key] ? [...rows[key], value] : [value]
                }
            });

            return Object.entries(rows).map(([item, values]) => (
                <TableRow
                    hover
                    key={item}
                    onClick={() => {
                        console.log(item)
                        props.handle_row_click(item)
                        setSelectedID(item)
                    }}
                    selected={selectedID === item}
                    classes={{ hover: classes.hover, selected: classes.selected }}
                    className={classes.tableRow}
                >
                    {
                        values.map((val, index) =>
                            <TableCell className={classes.tableCell}>{val}</TableCell>)
                    }
                </TableRow>
            ))

        } else { console.log('no headers') }
    }

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                <TableContainer className={classes.container}>
                    <Table
                        className={classes.table}
                        aria-labelledby="tableTitle"
                        size='small'
                        aria-label="enhanced table"
                    >
                        <TableHead>
                            <TableRow style={{ backgroundColor: 'grey' }}>
                                {renderTH(rows)}
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableHead>
                        <TableBody>
                            {renderTB(rows)}
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                </TableContainer>

            </Paper>

        </div>
    );
}
```

here is the table-data format that I fetch from API,

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by ` I need to get two-row indexes (like Xth row and Yth row).`?

Comment: @AnkushVerma like, selecting any two rows and this will give me the indexes of those two rows. ( i have edited the qst)